# LRU Cache is supposed to be (1) - Why does it contain an O(N) operation and still considered constant time?

Tags: java, data-structures

I recently started a data structures course and have been trying to understand the most basic of caches - the LRU Cache. From my understanding, the LRU cache is considered attractive because it uses O(1) complexity by amalgamating the best of HashMap and LinkedList.

I wrote the code but for 1 operation - all operations are O(1). But doesnt the data structure base on the slowest man in the army in the sense if there is even 1 operation that is O(N) then the whole datastructure is O(N)?
So because of the remove(key) in my code, wont LRU cache be infact O(N)?

```
    public void put(String key, String value) {
        if (!localCache.containsKey(key)) { // O(1)
            if (localCache.size() == MAX_SIZE) {
                String removedKey = localList.removeLast();
                localCache.remove(removedKey); // O(1)
            }
            localCache.put(key, value); // O(1))
            localList.addFirst(key); // O(1)
        } else {
            localCache.put(key, value); // O(1))
            localList.remove(key); // O(N). <<<<<--- THIS is O(N)
            localList.addFirst(key); // O(1)
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't LRU cache be O(N)

Comment: Don't store strings in the map, store doubly linked list nodes, so you can remove from there in constant time.

Comment: Isn't it in [amortized constant time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis), not constant time?

Comment: Each operation over the collection have its own complexity. There is no such thign as a "complexity of datastructure". For Example, `LinkedList` have O(1) for add and delete operations and O(n) for indexing, `ArrayList` have O(n) for add/delete and O(1) for indexing.

Comment: @Welbog do you mean dont store the  actual String value in the map but rather store the DLL node as the value?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that your `put` operation is O(N), but that's because you've implemented it incorrectly.

In an LRU cache, the hash map entry and the linked list node are the *same* object.  When you find an entry in the cache via the hash map, you have also found the linked list node, and you can remove it directly with no search.  The `linkedList.remove(key)` operation should never be called.

In Java, an LRU cache is implemented with `LinkedHashMap`.